# Is there a way to see which email address an email was sent to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have two different email addresses for my work email; one which is .co.uk and the other .com. Is there some way to tell looking at messages in my inbox which address an email was sent to?

I can't tell the version I'm using, but since it is with Office 365, I'm assuming it gets auto-update to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to look at the *Internet headers* to see that type of information.

Open the email in a stand-alone reading pane and then go to file > properties > internet headers to find the information you need.

Comment: Also, open the email, and hover over the To name (to you) and the Contact pop-up will open. Pull down the arrow and you can see the address of the sender

Comment: I don't need to see the address of the sender, I need to see which of *my* addresses the email was sent to.

Comment: It's insane that there's no way to view the original "To" address outside of the headers. I wanted the "To" address in a column but I have to use code to extract this information: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/outlooks-internet-headers/